# SO for Teams: can we break into multiple spaces / sub-organizations?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

We work with Stack Overflow for Teams, with two different internal organisations: Engineering and Product.

We use tags to separate the questions+answers between the teams, and there was a question of whether we can create two sibling communities (such as Stack Overflow and Server Fault) in the Teams product?

If some users will be active in both communities - will we need to pay for them twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, pricing does seem to be on a per-team basis.

You can also consider [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise), which is a stand-alone installation of the Q&A platform for your company, and you can create unlimited Teams in there as needed.